# powershell threading help using poshrsjob module

Tags: multithreading, powershell, start-job

I am trying to multithread something and ran across this:
http://learn-powershell.net/2015/03/31/introducing-poshrsjob-as-an-alternative-to-powershell-jobs/

Attempting to use but getting errors and not able to access the data I need. Let me explain. I have an extremely simple example here:

```
@('12.34.56.78')|Start-RSJob -Name {"TEST_$($_)"} -ScriptBlock {
    Param($Computername)
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computername -Quiet
}

get-RSJob|Receive-RSJob
```

This actually errors saying computername is null. Any type of command I place in here same error comes up saying computername is null. How to get rid of this and how to access the Boolean value that should be returned.
This returns a true or false on the command line but I cannot access this value when run in this script.

Eventually this will need to take an array of IP's and I will need to access all values returned for each machine. I don't have to use this posh module but need threads and thought this a good choice. Any advice here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you found a bug in my module with using Param() to host the incoming data in the pipeline. Fortunately, you can work around this by just using `$_` in the scriptblock.

```
@('12.34.56.78')|Start-RSJob -Name {"TEST_$($_)"} -ScriptBlock {
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet
}

get-RSJob|Receive-RSJob
```

That being said, I definitely need to stomp that bug.

Edit: The issue with returning a $False is a bug ($True returns fine) in Receive-RSJob. I'll fix that as well.

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks. I am able to get around the exact issue using $_ .  The "true" value output though is still not visible in the script, but is visible on the command line when running get receive. I have need to pass in another argument using Param and when trying to get the output I am not able, in the script and on the command line this returns the null error.  Any suggestions on how to get the output, in the script? thanks.

Comment: For the extra parameter in the scriptblock, you can use $Using:<parametername> instead and it will pass it through into the scriptblock. I'll have to test $True output in a script and see what can be done with that.

Comment: What version of PoshRSJob are you running? `(Get-Module -Name PoshRSJob).Version`

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-Module -Name PoshRSJob).Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      5      5      1

Comment: I mostly finished this using $_ but my results are off, I suspect due to thread safe. I assume this module supports something like $port_array = [array] synchronize(@())? If not... can you or someone suggest how to make thread safe? thanks again.

Comment: You are correct in that this supports thread safe collections like what you supplied in your previous comment. Also, I updated the module to version 1.5.5.3 that fixes the issues that you were originally seeing.